# How to remove null characters in excel 2007?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have a data that has blank cells. However, this are not actually blank. If i used teh =isblank() function, it returns false.

I got this code from a website

```
Sub NoNull()
Dim c As Range
 For Each c In Selection
    If c.Value = " " Then c.ClearContents
 Next c
End Sub
```

As instructed, I highlight the column that I need to clear those blank cells. However, when i run it from the Visual Basic Editor (Excel 2007), im not seeing any effect. The cells still contain those null character. Note; I assume the character is " ". I am not really sure how to verify that.

Dixi

Editted:
The code above works. initially i dont have a space between c.Value = "spacehere". Thanks to gary's suggestion. I made it work.

Comment: Use `=LEN(<cell>)=0` to check for empty cell instead of `=isblank(<cell>)`

Comment: In your macro make sure there is space between the pair of double quotes or follow Santosh's advice.

Comment: Thank you Santosh. Howeever, what I truely need is to clear the contents of that blank cells. Since I got 60k data, i just cant do it manually. and i just tried, gary's solution.. hahahha.. it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see my editted post above. This has been resolved. There is a missing space between " and ".

Should be
c.Value = "spacehere"

The column needs to highlighted before you run the program. Might take a while if you have a large data set. I think this code only works for a single column at a time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Select the cells and click on Clear (Under Editing Group )